# How do I connect to a local server run by Aptana from an outside network?

Tags: networking

I have a rails server that i run from Aptana Studio. I normally connect to it via localhost:300, and everyone on the network connects to it via stonecrab:3000 (stonecrab is the name of my computer). However, how do I allow people from outside the local network to connect to the server? For instance, if the IP of my internet connection is 123.456.7.8, what URL can someone use in a web browser to connect to my server? I have a linksys e1000 router and i can access it if i need to change any settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your machine will not be accessible from behind the router. You need to enable port forwarding in your router. You need to tell your router to forward port 3000 to the IP of stonecrab. Then you will use 123.456.7.8:3000 to access stonecrabe:3000 from outside the LAN.