# Can I get hostname on CSS

Tags: html, css

```
.trPic{ 
width:640px; 
height:480px; 
position:absolute; 
top:0px;
left:0px; 
width:640px; 
height:480px; 
background: url(http://192.168.2.150:8090/?action=stream) no-repeat; 
border:0px solid #000000; 
}
```

Can I get hostname on Css? Something like (http://hostname:8090/?action=stream)
  because my server running on diffirent port and when my ip changes or when someone connected from out of lan i can't see stream...

When my ip changes example : 192.168.43.187 i have to change css file to and localhost uses 127.0.1.1 and dosemn't show on the lan when i want to stream out of lan i have to change css to http://publicip:8090/?action=stream

Comment: Yes, it should work, but have you not tried?

Comment: It might not be a good idea to use localhost. you can, however use a relative reference like `/?action=stream` - note that the static media needs to be configured to serve properly on this url

Comment: Go explore /etc/hosts or Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts (Linux/Windows dependant) and see how localhost is defined, then just add your own input.

Comment: @GavinSimpson i tried but it dosen'T work on out of lan and my local ip changes...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a local server run by Aptana from an outside network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780992/how-do-i-connect-to-a-local-server-run-by-aptana-from-an-outside-network)

Comment: @Sheepy i port forwarded it from router but it only works when i wrote the my public ip instead of 192.168.2.150

Comment: I think you might have to set your streamer to broadcast on localhost.

Comment: @HalilDemircan Any IP that starts with 192.168 is internal use only.  They cannot be used externally - even if you know them, the other networks (e.g. your ISP) doesn't, and so cannot route you back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the image manually
you dont need to host your image bro XD

```
.trPic{ 
width:640px; 
height:480px; 
position:absolute; 
top:0px;
left:0px; 
width:640px; 
height:480px; 
background: url(/*ur_image*/) no-repeat; 
border:0px solid #000000; 
}
```

Comment: Thank but I solved it and thats not work because image is on another port :D I just basicly used javascript :D

Comment: can you vote for my post please? XD ill apreciate it